# connect docker container with python-eve app to docker container with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask, docker-compose, eve

I am following [this tutorial](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html) on *python-eve*. I use *docker* container for *mongodb* and python3 for *eve*.

It works fine if I use *venv* for the *eve* app, but I cannot connect to the *mongo* container, if I run my *eve* app in another *docker* container. I always get the following error in the *eve* app: **pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused**. Although, I am still able to connect to the *mongo* container manually.

#### What I have done so far

I searched around and tried a few propositions, which did not work out.

- I changed the *bindip* in the *mongod.conf* to *0.0.0.0*.
- I removed the *bindip* line completely.
- I tried to start the *mongodb* as `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`.
- I tried to remove completely all containers and start fresh.

My *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.3'

volumes:

  mongodata:

services:

  mongodb:
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    image: mongo:3.4
    volumes: 
      - mongodata:/data/db
    env_file:
      - environments/local.env
    expose:
      - 27017

  api:
    container_name: 'mymoney'
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb
```

My *Dockerfile* for the *eve* app:

```
FROM python:3.6
MAINTAINER alpy

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libffi-dev python3-dev

RUN mkdir -p /app/src
# We copy the requirements.txt file first to avoid cache invalidations
COPY requirements.txt /app/src
WORKDIR /app/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/src
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

I have no idea, what else I can do. Need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared, that the `MONGO_HOST` in the `settings.py` of the app, must be set to the *mongo* container name as specified in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
...
MONGO_HOST = 'mongodb'
...
```